# Array foreach() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declared array and added variables inside so now I want to create one click function with javascript but I have no idea how I tried this but not working

```
    function volumeUpDown(){
        let a = $('._1');
        let b = $('._2');
        let c = $('._3');
        let d = $('._4');
        let e = $('._5');
        let f = $('._6');
        let g = $('._7');
        let ar = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
        ar.forEach().click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('volactive');
        })
    }
    volumeUpDown();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the whole thing in one jQuery call:

```
$('._1, ._2, ._3, ._4, ._5, ._6, ._7').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("volactive");
});
```

The comma in the selector string lets you ask for multiple different matches to be collected into the jQuery object. The jQuery object is *already* an array (sort-of) and jQuery functions like `.click()` will do their work for all elements in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Just for dynamic purposes, in case you need to someday add more dynamically (using still a single jQuery call, which is the correct approach anyway)

```
$(Array.from({length: 7},(_,i) => `._{$i + 1}`).join(', ')).click(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("volactive") 
});
```

The first part will generate the selector:

```js
const selector = Array.from({length: 7},(_,i) => `._${i + 1}`).join(', ');
console.log(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the object and apply the callback.

```
ar.forEach(o => o.click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('volactive');
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use `forEach`:

```
ar.forEach(elem => elem.click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("volactive");
}));
```